# MongoDB. Find all document where element array have on of the needed element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongodb documents

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
  "name" : ["Some Name","Another"],
  "zipcode" : ["2223"]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
  "name" : ["Another", "Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2224"]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000003"),
  "name" : ["Yet", "Another", "Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2225"]
}
```

I need to find elements where "name array" have " Another ", "Name" values.
I tried to use $in, but if there more values, like in

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000003"),
  "name" : ["Yet", "Another", "Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2225"]
}
```

It doesn't return it =(

Comment: Could you show the `$in` syntax you used? Given the comments on the answers, it's not clear what you've tried and what you really expect.

Comment: We can also add that in cleaning up this question, there **were** different spaces at the end of and around the word "Another" in the array elements. If this is what your data is actually like then none of the values are equal because they all had different whitespace arrangements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of $in should be fine (as explained below) as long as your data is correct and the values **do not** contain any whitespace. But if they are not **exactly** the same you are going to need to do some [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) matching, also using the [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) form:

```
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
       {name: {$regex: 'Another'} },
       {name: {$regex: 'Name'}} 
    ]
})
```

If you just want to get the one document that has both of, and **only** the fields values you want, and in the **same order** just supply the argument as an array:

```
db.collection.find({ name: ["Another", "Name" ] })
```

The usage of [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is to match **any** of the elements you supply as a list. In this case you would match all of your documents

```
db.collection.find({ name: {$in: [ "Another", "Name" ] } })
```

For the [$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator, it's function is to match **all** of elements contained in your argument list, so if an argument was not present in the array being searched it would not be included. So just the last two would match:

```
db.collection.find({ name: {$all: [ "Another", "Name" ] } })


{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
  "name" : ["Another", "Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2224"]
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000003"),
  "name" : ["Yet", "Another", "Name"],
  "zipcode" : ["2225"]
}
```

Finally, if you **don't know** the order of the elements you are matching, while a little contrived, [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) gives you a way to *get out of jail*:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match using $all to reduce the list
    {$match: {name: {$all: ["Name","Another"] }}},

    // Keep the original document in the _id
    {$project:{ 
        _id: {
            _id: "$_id",
            name: "$name",
            zipcode: "$zipcode"
        },
        name: 1
    }},

    // Unwind the "name" array
    {$unwind: "$name"},


    // Count up the entries per _id
    {$group: { _id: "$_id", count: {$sum: 1}}},

    // Only match *2* as there were two elements we were expecting
    {$match: {count: 2} },

    // Project back to the original form
    {$project: { 
        _id:0,
        _id: "$_id._id",
         name: "$_id.name",
         zipcode: "$_id.zipcode"
     }} 
])
```

And that's all the forms I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the MongoDB documentation for `$in`?
Find it [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

You'll need to do this:

```
find({name: { $in: [ "Another", "Name"] }})
```

Comment: The question says they were using $in. Try it yourself, you will not get **only** single document that the question asks for. Then read the documentation yourself and understand why.

Comment: What single document is he asking for? As I understand from the question, he's looking for any document that has both Another and Name values in the array. `find({name: { $in: [ "Another", "Name"] }})` will return both the second and third documents, no matter of the order of the values in the array.

I think that what he did try was the first example you gave and that's why it didn't match his 3rd document. That's at least what I understand from the question.

Comment: I'd agree with Yev. @NeilLunn -- I think more clarification is necessary about the question, and that the title of the question likely should have been "**One** of the needed elements"

Comment: @WiredPrairie Possibly not clear, yes. The english is not hot. And possibly it's one, possibly it's many, possibly the data is borked and that is affecting results. But in general, just trying to list all the permutations so that there is something to look at before the question turns into a stream of comments like "I tried what you said and it didn't work"